# C# Add two different objects into list

Tags: c#, list

Hi I want to add two different objects into a list object.

The code is as follows:

```
try
{
    List<SerializeCls> serclsres = new List<SerializeCls>();

    serclsres = pr2.FirstMethod();

    serclsres = pr1.GenerateFile();                        
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<SerializeCls>)); //SerializeCls//,extratypes//SerializeCls
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(string path, FileMode.Create))
    {                                
        xs.Serialize(fs,serclsres);
        fs.Close();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Succesfully serialized to XML");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

From the above code I want to add `pr2.FirstMethod` & `pr1.GenerateFile` into list object `serclsres`
Please help me to solve this. I am new to C#.

Comment: What's the error? What are the return types of those methods?

Comment: Can you put the SerializeCls Class code?

Comment: you can use `serclsres.Add(object)` if both of your method returns the same object

Comment: What are the return types of `FirstMethod` and `GenerateFile`?

Comment: @ Michael Perrenoud It will give this error "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleTask5SerialwithAdd.SerializeCls>' to 'ConsoleTask5SerialwithAdd.SerializeCls'"

Comment: @ Jon Skeet return type is List<>

Comment: @Dharani, by any chance do you intend to do something like `serclsres.AddRange(pr2.FirstMethod());` ?

Comment: The question is very unclear. It would have helped if you had said this in the first place. Also note that the accepted answer is creating a list with two elements, each of which is a list; whereas the comment above of which you say that "it works" is actually first adding all elements from one list, then all elements from the other, to create a list with _n_ + _m_ elements each of which is a `SerializeCls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this error `"cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleTask5SerialwithAdd.SerializeCls>' to 'ConsoleTask5SerialwithAdd.SerializeCls'`"

Try this

```
List<List<SerializeCls>> serclsres = new List<List<SerializeCls>()>;
serclsres.Add(pr2.FirstMethod());
serclsres.Add(pr1.GenerateFile());
```

So you will have a collection of lists, a "List of Lists".

Answer (score 3):

```
List<List<SerializeCls>> serclsres = new List<List<SerializeCls>>();
serclsres.Add(pr2.FirstMethod());
serclsres.Add(pr1.GenerateFile());
```

If you want some `serclsres` to have type `List<SerializeCls>`, you have to use `AddRange` like this:

```
List<SerializeCls> serclsres = new List<SerializeCls>();
serclsres.AddRange(pr2.FirstMethod());
serclsres.AddRange(pr1.GenerateFile());
```

Comment: It will give this error "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleTask5SerialwithAdd.SerializeCls>' to 'ConsoleTask5SerialwithAdd.SerializeCls'"

Comment: @DharaniRadhakrishnanR what's the return type of `FirstMethod` and `GenerateFile`?